# How to use CSP to access keystore on HW token in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, cryptography

I am new to CSP and I would like to get the start point how to use it from C#.
I was googling how to use it but I don't get it or maybe it wasn't clear to me due to inexperience.

I have a library "tokencsp.dll" together with signature file "tokencsp.sig" which should provide access and functions on my HW cryptographic token.

How to inicialize CSP through dll library in C# and access keystore on token?

Any starting point or working example would be great.